# iis 7 play sound

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7

I have a vcf project.  My problem is my service isn't playing wave sounds.  When debugging vs2010 will play sounds, but if I use a web server (iis 7), the sound is not playing.  I know it's an unusual request but this server is special and it is talking people.  I am using system.media lib and my object is SoundPlayer.

Comment: Can you tell us *why* you'd want a server to play a sound? It is, as you say, a very unusual request.

Comment: It is not logical to play sound in a service!IIS is designed for giving service to remote clients so how a user around the world can hear the sound in a remote server!

Comment: i know what is iis what can do. but it is experimental work. it is like a internet controlled robot http://www.shelato.com/SecurityRobot/

Comment: @Jon Hey, never underestimate the power of a "lively" server room. Servers work better when there is high morale :)

Comment: If a tree falls in a server room and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Process to run a separate process with your sound player. I'm not at all sure that this is what you are looking for.